# is it possible to overload the increment operator (++) to increment by more than 1?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to overload the increment operator (++) to increment by more than 1? If yes, isn't that violating the way the operator is supposed to function?

Comment: Maybe if your class represents a number sequence then it would be ok to increment by another number. Something like even numbers, or prime numbers or whatever.

Comment: With a couple of exceptions, you can overload _any_ operator to do almost anything you like.

Comment: I remember some legacy code where `operator++()` increments row whereas `operator ++(int)` increments column of a matrix iterator :-/

Comment: It is common convention when defining operators on custom types to be as consistent as possible with how built-in types work. Even in @wally 's example, you would have a custom type which is logically incremented by one even if a stored value is incremented by another amount.

Comment: In C++ you can even overload bit shift operators to perform I/O!

Comment: @el.pescado No, no. Nobody would ever do that with C++.

Comment: BTW, `operator++` is *not* "increment by one operator". See what happens if you use it on pointer types.

Comment: @el.pescado will it increment pointers by more than one object?

Comment: @Gerhardh, one object is rarely 1 byte, so the increment is not exactly "+1".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For custom types: Yes you can.

> isn't that violating the way the operator is supposed to function

If your type models a number, then yes, absolutely. Which is why this usually is a very bad idea indeed. However, `++` more generally means “go to the next logical element”. For a numeric type, this is indeed expected to be 1 more than the current value.

But the operator generalises to sequences, which can have other properties. In the example given by Jesper, [if your type represents the sequence of the Fibonacci numbers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d615a3fb1509d0cc), then `++` should progress the sequence to the next Fibonacci number (and similarly for other sequences).

Incidentally, C++ does have an “increment by *n*” operator: `+=`.

Comment: If the operator is designed to give you the next number of the Fibonacci sequence, then it would be fine. +1 is not always the right answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is an excellent point, let me update my answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is still "increase one", the one is increased in the index of Fibonacci sequence....

Comment: You could also have a "by 7" iterator.

Comment: In other words, the subtle difference between F(n+1) and (Fn)+1

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic already does this, in a sense. It increments by `sizeof(*ptr)` bytes. Of course, that's so that you move to the next object, so it logically is an increment of one.

This is a common theme in C++. Overloading should behave logically correct; the internal details have to follow. For a linked list, `operator++` should move to the next element in the list, not the next element in memory. Internally that typically translates to something like `ptr = ptr->next` instead of `ptr = ptr+1`.

Answer (score 0):

For a user-defined type, overloading the increment operator **only** means that you've provided a function that can be called with `++`. That is, it's just a syntactic convenience; it does not impose any restrictions on what that function does. So, yes, you can write it to increment by more than one. You can also write it to always return 42, or launch a game of Tetris. Of course, when you're designing such a function you have to consider whether its behavior would surprise someone who is using your code.